# Apache crashes in a loop of string concatenation

Tags: php, apache, loops, crash, string-concatenation

I have a script that opens a huge XLSX file and reads 3000 rows of data, saving it to a two dimensional array. Of all places for Apache to crash, it does so in a simple loop that builds a MySQL query. I know this because if I remove the following lines from my application, it runs without issue:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `map.lmds.dots` VALUES";

foreach($data as $i => $row)
{
    $id = $row["Abonnementsid"];
    $eier = $row["Eier"];
    $status = $row["Status"];

    if($i !== 0) $query .= "\n,";

    $query .= "('$id', '$eier', '$status', '0', '0')";
}

echo $query;
```

I can't see a thing wrong with the code.

I'm using PHPExcel and dBug.php

**Why is this script crashing Apache?**

---

**EDIT:** Perhaps I should elaborate on what I mean by crash. I mean a classic Windows "Program has stopped working":

[image]

---

**EDIT:** Another attempt inspired by one of the answers. Apache still crashes:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `map.lmds.dots` VALUES";
$records = array();

foreach($data as $i => &$row)
{
    $id = $row["Abonnementsid"];
    $eier = $row["Eier"];
    $status = $row["Status"];

    $records[] = "('$id', '$eier', '$status', '0', '0')";
}

echo $query . implode(",", $records);
```

---

**EDIT:** I have narrowed it down further. As soon as I add a foreach loop, Apache crashes.

```
foreach($data as $i => $row) {};
```

Comment: When you say "Apache crashes" what you do mean? Is it reporting an error code, or does the screen just go blank? Have you checked the error logs for a specific error? (It's likely that there will be one in there.)

Comment: It's most likely to be a memory issue, so what steps are you taking to reduce memory usage? For example, PHPExcel provides a cell caching mechanism to reduce its memory overheads... are you using that? Have you tried reading the workbook in chunks? Can you insert into MySQL as you read from the workbook, or do you need to build that large 2d array first?

Comment: I suppose I should insert stuff into MySQL as I go. But still, I have set more than enough available memory. I edited in the error so you can see

Comment: In any case, I had memory issues earlier which resulted in PHP exiting with an error message. Now I have more than enough memory available, and Apache crashes. I doubt the memory amount is the issue.

Comment: Have you checked the error logs for a specific error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it turns out that updating PHP from 5.3.1 to 5.3.5 made the problem go away. I still have no idea as to what made PHP crash in the first place, but I suppose my PHP could simply have been broken and in need of a reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others respondents have said this is most likely a memory issue, you should check both your Apache error logs and your PHP error logs for more info.

Assuming this is a memory problem, I suggest you change your code so that you execute multiple insert statements inside the foreach loop rather than storing the whole thing in a big string and sending it to the database all at once.  Of course, this means that you're making 3000+ calls to the database rather than just one, I'd expect this to be a bit slower, you can mitigate this problem by using a prepared statement which should be a bit more efficient.  If this is still too slow, try changing your loop so that you only call the database every `N` times round the loop.

Comment: I have checked the error logs, and they only contain notices about starting apache after it crashes. It contains absolutely nothing regarding my script. Also, I'm not contacting a database at all in my script. It crashes in building the string. In my experience, PHP should handle strings of half a million characters or so easily.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of string concatenation and the amount of string data involved could be too much to handle at once during the permitted execution time.

You could try to just collect the values in an array and put them together at the end:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `map.lmds.dots` VALUES";
$records = array();
foreach($data as $i => $row) {
    $records[] = "('".mysql_real_escape_string($row["Abonnementsid"])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($row["Eier"])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($row["Status"])."', '0', '0')";
}
$query .= implode("\n,", $records);
```

Or insert the records in chunks:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `map.lmds.dots` VALUES";
$records = array();
foreach($data as $i => $row) {
    $records[] = "('".mysql_real_escape_string($row["Abonnementsid"])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($row["Eier"])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($row["Status"])."', '0', '0')";
    if ($i % 1000 === 999) {
        mysql_query($query . implode("\n,", $records));
        $records = array();
    }
}
if (!empty($records)) {
    mysql_query($query . implode("\n,", $records));
}
```

Also try it with reference in [`foreach`](http://php.net/control-structures.foreach) to avoid that an internal copy of the array is made:

```
foreach($data as $i => &$row) {
    // …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does sounds like a memory issue. Maybe it has nothing to do with the loop building the SQL query. It could be related to reading the "very" large file before that. And the loop pushing memory usage over the limit. Did you try freeing up memory after reading the file?

You can use memory_get_peak_usage() and memory_get_usage() to get some more info about consumed memory.

If that doesn't solve your issue. Install a debugger like Xdebug or Zend Debugger and do some profiling.

Comment: I had to double the memory limit to open the file. I have later doubled the momory limit again, so I doubt lack of memory is the problem. I will be trying the functions you suggested though, thanks!

Comment: I now unset all the variables associated with the file load before the loop starts. It still crashes Apache in the loop.